# Create node fields populated with an API

Tags: 8

I want to create a drop-down field on a content type, but I need this drop-down to be populate by an external API.

I think I need to have custom module, get data from API in module controller, after this steps I'm a bit lost, how can I populate my drop-down with API data?

This is an example of what I want.

[image: example]

After back-end users fill all the fields, I need to save them on the database and show them on the front-end.

Comment: See [options_allowed_values](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21options%21options.module/function/options_allowed_values/8.2.x) and this [blog post](https://chromatichq.com/blog/dynamic-default-and-allowed-values-list-fields-drupal-8)

Comment: This is a quite broad question. Since it's about code to write, we expect the question show the code you tried so far. The question doesn't make clear in what part exactly you have difficulties in writing the code.

Comment: hi kiamlaluno, right now I just need help to populate the dropbox with an external API. But I don't know where to start, have read some stuff like "field widget" but I am lost. I need help with a starting point, what kind of search I can make to achive this, documentation and so on, because I really don't know what to search/looking for

Comment: It all starts at the same place if you made a custom field. Whether you make a field widget or use hook_form_alter to affect that one specific form field, in both cases, you have to provide the plumbing to talk to the API, get the options, and then feed those options to the select element.